# endpoints-framework clientlibs version

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm building an API using Google Cloud Endpoints Framework v2 on Java AppEngine Standard.

Using Endpoints Framework means you can easily generate Java Client Library.

However I am unable to change version of this generated Client Library from maven pom or another way.

Is there a way to modify the version of the client library generated ?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the version of the client library by changing the version in your `@Api` annotation.

```
@Api(
     name = "echo",
     version = "v1", // Update this value
     // ...
```

The generated api client's `<version>` tag in the generated `pom.xml` will be prefixed with the api version (and will contain a suffix of the version of the google-api-client library used, as well an optional SNAPSHOT label if you're working with a snapshot).

An example `pom.xml` snippet for the above definition might look like:

```
<groupId>com.example.echo</groupId>
<artifactId>echo</artifactId>
<version>v2-1.25.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>echo v2-1.25.0-SNAPSHOT</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```